# Unload all loaded packages

Tags: r

I've looked at this but couldn't readily find how to do it. I tried to write up some function that fails with the error:

> Error in unloadNamespace(x) : 
>     namespace ‘graphics’ is imported by ‘stats and other packages here'

However, many of these packages are not even on the `search` list.

```
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[6] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

This is the function I was playing with:

```
lapply(gsub("package:","",search()[grep(".*(?<=package:)",search(),perl = T)]),
       function(x) unloadNamespace(x))
```

A variant that doesn't work:

```
lapply(gsub("package:","",search()[grep(".*(?<=package:)",search(),perl = T)]),
       function(x) detach(x))
```

**Question**:
How can I best unload several packages(better if I could unload them all)?

Answer (score 12):

A simpler solution to unload all non-base packages:

```
lapply(names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs), function(pkgs)
  detach(
    paste0('package:', pkgs),
    character.only = T,
    unload = T,
    force = T
  ))
```

Comment: FYI - it worked but it threw a bunch of warnings saying packages could not be unloaded. However, when I ran `(.packages())` afterwards, only the base R packages remained.

Comment: I assume that there were packages that could not be unloaded without a warning because other packages still loaded did need them.

Answer (score 8):

I typically run something like this to unload all non-base packages:

```
detachAllPackages <- function() {
  basic.packages.blank <- c(    
    "stats",    
    "graphics",    
    "grDevices",    
    "utils",   
    "datasets",  
    "methods",    
    "base"    
  )    
  basic.packages <- paste("package:", basic.packages.blank, sep = "")   
  package.list <- search()[ifelse(unlist(gregexpr("package:", search())) == 1, TRUE, FALSE)]   
  package.list <- setdiff(package.list, basic.packages)   
  if (length(package.list) > 0) {   
    for (package in package.list) {   
      detach(package, character.only = TRUE)   
    }   
  }    
}

detachAllPackages()
```